# Knockout data-binding browser tools

Tags: dom, data-binding, knockout.js, browser, knockout-2.0

How can I trigger a data-bind property from browser tools? In the example below, how can I set showDiv to true or false from browser tools?

```
    <div data-bind="visible:showDiv">Text</div>
```

Comment: It depends how you have created your viewmodel and whether you have a reference for it. Or you can get the element with jQuery or similar and you the `ko.dataFor` to get the datacontext and change the property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you would explicitly set a value in code, you can set your observable values from the console like this:

```
viewModel.showDiv(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

first, you don't trigger a data-bind, you can trigger an observable bound to a binding handler  inside the data-bind,

where in your example, suppose that `showDiv` is an observable, whenever you update that observable, it will trigger the update method of the `visible` binding handler in your data-bind.

now as generic way not only limited to your case,
the simplest way is to make use of the `$0` shortcut in developer tools ( Chrome & Firefox ) which will get you the last inspected DOM elements, along with either `ko.dataFor` or `ko.contextFor` methods, where they accept a DOM element as an argument.

whenever you want to see the underlying view model for any element you see on the page, and to update your view model's property ( in case they are observables ), do the following:

1. open the developer tools
2. inspect your desired DOM element ( once you've inspected it, it will be available in the console as `$0` variabl )
3. now you can get the underlying view model behind that DOM element by using `ko.dataFor( $0 )`

   ```
   ko.dataFor( $0 ).showDiv( true );   // your div is visible
   ko.dataFor( $0 ).showDiv( false );  // not visible
   ```

in a more complex scenarios ( inside a foreach, or when having nested view models), you might want to use `ko.contextFor( $0 )`

Comment: There's a Chrome extension that shortens this to `edit$data.showDiv(true)`. It also (among other things) adds a panel in devTools that shows the Knockout context of the currently selected DOM element! Never code Knockout without it! (No, I didn't write this extension - I really do love it that much.) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Is there a real requirement to do this from browser tools? Can't you just create a button that calls a function in your view model to toggle it's value if it's for testing?

**In your viewmodel (assuming you have an observable for `showDiv`):**

```
var self = this;

self.showDiv = ko.observable(true);

self.toggleDiv = function () {
    self.showDiv(!self.showDiv());
}
```

**Then:**

```
<div data-bind="visible:showDiv">Text</div>
<input type="button" value="Toggle" data-bind="click: toggleDiv" />
```

Example in: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kNa7/1/)

Otherwise I'd just create a breakpoint in the JS file and use the console to change it's value.